# Problems running ServiceStack as daemon on Linux (Ubuntu 13) as described on the wiki page

Tags: apache, ubuntu, servicestack

I have a problem running ServiceStack as daemon on Linux.

I just started to work into creating a REST API with C# on Mono. I studied your Wiki about it and yesterday I tried to run ServiceStack as daemon on Linux (Ubuntu 13) **exactly** as described on the wiki page:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux

But I encountered a problem, tried every possible solution I found in the web, but nothing helped.. The problem:

If I access `http://127.0.0.1:8080` on the Ubuntu System everything is fine and I am beeing redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/metadata` and get the Service Metadata.

If I access `http://127.0.0.1:80` I get the static content. Also fine.

BUT if I access `http://127.0.0.1/api` I'm being redirected to `http://127.0.0.1/metadata` and get a 404. Which is absolutely understandable because there is no such thing on Port 80.
You know I'm not that good in apache, but after reading the configuration mentioned in the wiki I thought this should work normally. Am I wrong? Or do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Another problem is that if i access the service on my ubuntu system from another system, e.g. Windows through `http://ubuntu-dev:8080`, I get *Bad Request (invalid host)*.
I also get the 404 there if I access`http://ubuntu-dev/api`.

I think the Bad Request Thing must have something to do with servicestack because apache only listens on port 80 (as it should I think). Do you have any suggestions about this?

It would be really nice if someone could help me because I really don't know what to do with these problems.

Greetings, daily

Comment: Have you looked at the apache access and error logs?
Are you sure you properly installed and activated mod_proxy as mentioned in the wiki?

Because you can't access the /api URL it would suggest that the proxy is improperly configured.
Make sure you have a look at the log files and see what they say exactly.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. I installed everythink like mentioned in the wiki. But in the meantime I switched to plain apache2 with mod-mono which now works allmost very well. But because of this I can't give more info for debugging :( But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem that only occurs when it runs on a different port than 80.
Probably it's not redirecting properly when a port is set.
Try running it on nginx with fastcgi (fastcgi-mono-server4), there you can run it on port 80.

Comment: Nginx was no option, but thank you ;) As you can read above this question is not longer important to me.

Comment: Hi again :) After having massive problems with Apache, Mono and Https+Auth I gave ServiceStack another chance. As you mentioned I tried NginX and well, everything is working very well :) Including HTTPS and Auth. So we can say the issue is solved.